# Assets. Why OpenFD depends on the type of file?

Tags: android, midi, assets

I put file alma_mater.kar into folder assets/sounds
When I try to get AssetsFileDescriptor, an error occurs

```
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = this.getResources().getAssets().openFd("sounds/alma_mater.kar");
]
```

When I put renamed file alma_mater.mid, no errors.
Why?
Project based on Google API [Android 2.2] on eclipse
My device is LG P500 (Optimus One) updated to V20d (Android 2.3.3)

> 03-15 10:23:15.959: W/System.err(32076):
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file
>   descriptor; it is probably compressed 
> 03-15 10:23:15.959:
>   W/System.err(32076):  at
>   android.content.res.AssetManager.openAssetFd(Native Method) 
> 03-15
>   10:23:15.959: W/System.err(32076):    at
>   android.content.res.AssetManager.openFd(AssetManager.java:330)

Answer (score 0):

Based on a quick google search and the contents of your exception, I suspect that Android is treating KAR files as ["keep-it archive" files](http://www.file-extensions.org/kar-file-extension-keep-it-archive-file) rather than MIDI files. Is there any reason you can't keep it named with .mid and just parse it as a KAR file?